# Cannot use json-simple on Windows command line

Tags: java, command-prompt

I'm trying to run a Java program that needs the json-simple-1.1.1.jar files.

I can compile the files using 
    javac -cp json-simple-1.1.1.jar *.java
but when i run 
    java -cp json-simple-1.1.1.jar Server
I get the following error:
Error: Could not find or load main class Server

The class Server does exist and I can run the same sequence of commands in Linux with no problems, but I can't get it to work on Windows. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Run with `java -jar "json-simple-1.1.1.jar"`.

OR

`java -cp "json-simple-1.1.1.jar"`.

Comment: I get the error "no main manifest attribute, in json-simple-1.1.1.jar". I don't think the jar file contains a main method. Its just a helper library.

Comment: Oh. Do you need to run the helper library? Run the application that requires the helper library.

Answer (score 0):

From the same directory as you run javac, just run:

```
$ java -cp json-simple-1.1.1.jar your-java-file-with-main-method-and-without-java-extension
```